# Plotting Dynamic Data For A Graph Using Flot(JQuery)

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am new in Asp.Net Web development..........
I am working on a web form application which is using asp.net c#  and MS SQL Server 2008 as database. I want to plot a graph of trends based on time filters. Most importantly, I need to perform this using **jquery library flot.**

I want the units of trends points on y axis and date on x axis. I want to plot 4 different trends, so there will be 4 lines for 4 different trends over graph after plotting.I want to have **zooming & navigation features** too for the graph.

I know to fetch the data from db using web method, but how to collect this data?....... as a list or what & then how to format this data in to javascript function & plot the graph?

Below is the code snippets:

**html:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script src="js/flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
    <script src="js/flot/jquery.flot.selection.js"></script>
    <script src="js/flot/jquery.flot.navigate.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',               
                url: 'FlotChart.aspx/GetChartData',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    // Process data and plot the graph
                },
                error: function (data, success, error) {
                    debugger;
                    alert("Error : " + error);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    </form>
    <div>
    <div id="chart1"></div>
    </div>   
</body>
```

**Code:**

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<ChartResult> GetChartData()
    {

        List<ChartResult> LstChartResData = new List<ChartResult>();

        DataSet dsResult = new objDA().Get_ChartData();
        for (int iCount = 0; iCount < dsResult.Tables[0].Rows.Count; iCount++)
        {
            ChartResult objChartRes = new ChartResult();
            objChartRes.date = Convert.ToDateTime(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[iCount]["date"]);
            objChartRes.load = Convert.ToDecimal(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[iCount]["load"]);
            objChartRes.whlth = Convert.ToDecimal(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[iCount]["whlth"]);
            objChartRes.audio = Convert.ToDecimal(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[iCount]["audio"]);
            objChartRes.ohlth = Convert.ToDecimal(dsResult.Tables[0].Rows[iCount]["ohlth"]);

            LstChartResData.Add(objChartRes);
        }

        return LstChartResData;
    }

public class ChartResult
{
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public decimal load { get; set; }
    public decimal whlth { get; set; }
    public decimal audio { get; set; }
    public decimal ohlth { get; set; }
}
```

Now how to process the result data into sucess and use the flot library function as per referenced script flot files?

Can anybody help me to perform this?.

Thanks in advance.

- Regards

Comment: What have you tried and how does it vary from the documentation for your chosen graphing library?

Comment: Hello Nathan.......I have updated my post, can u please help me out now to plot the graph?.....Thanks.

Comment: WebAPI is a more modern framework for the server-side implementation of such service methods and facilitates the return of JSON objects (which will then be usable on the client side in a much easier fashion)... in short, you're building with old technology.  Google for "c# webapi tutorial" and follow that for your server-side code.  (also, learn about disposing objects: your database object isn't disposed and will cause problems in production).  When you have an array of javascript objects on the client side, then you're in a position to start worrying about charting something. Good Luck! :)

Comment: Hello Nathan......thanks for the reply.I know I am using old technology, but this project is old & following this architecture only.The Question is how do I proces the result data into sucess and use the flot library function as per referenced script flot files?.........Can anyone help/suggest me?

Comment: Ok.  So your ajax call succeeds and you have the data on the client?  If so, then have you viewed the source of the examples at http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/  ?

Comment: Hello Nathan......Thanks for the reply, ajax call succeeds and I have the data on the client........I have viewed the code samples already referred by link u sent, but I am stuck up at making the coordinates array, formatting the date values & plot these datapoints over graph, can anybody suggest the solution?